# How to calculate displacement from Accelerometer reading?

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, frequency

I have accelerometer readings of three axis X, Y and z, will be getting data in a frequency of (62 records per second). Could you please suggest me how can I calculate the displacement.

Data in hand:
Accelerometer readings with respect to time.

Do I need to calculate the displacement using time domain data or need to convert into frequency domain. Which one will give a accurate results?

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can double integrate the acceleration vector over time to obtain the displacement. In theory this is a perfectly sensible solution.

But in practice, there will always be a component of `g` (acceleration due to gravity) acting on at least one of the axes all the time. Let's say you subtract the `g` component from your xyz vectors. The problem is that any slight error in readings (even off by a small order of magnitude) when double integration will lead to the error adding up over time rendering the displacement wildly inaccurate.

According to the integrated values, you will most likely see even an idle object fly off into space. You'll need an additional sensor to tell you the orientation - like a gyroscope, and have some point of reference (the Wiimote does this with an IR sensor).

This is primarily a time domain problem, but you could have a frequency domain stage where some amount of filtering is done to remove measurement error or process error.

tl;dr Positional tracking with acceleration sensors alone is a hard problem.

Comment: I have a list of number from my accelerometer. But what do you mean by acceleration vector? Can you give us an example?